# Vim. Use matchpairs option for jumping between start and end of spanish questions marks

Tags: regex, vim

Just as title says, I want matchpairs option to work with with the signs '¿' and '?'.  It works with other signs, for example after setting:

[image: Vim Screenshoot]

I'm able to jump between spanish exclamation marks ('¡' and '!') with just pressing '%'. The problem comes when doing the same with questions marks by:'

[image: Vim Screenshoot 2]

I will obtain a error message explaining some kind of function failing dealing with regex:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

At first sight, the function would seem to come from one of my plugins so I tried to find which by replacing my .vimrc with a blank file but vim continued showing the same error so my personal plugins are not the problem.

As far as I know, when using nocompatible mode in vim several integrated plugins are charged. I think some of those plugins is the guilty, because when I call vim without any config fail by "vim -u NONE" the problem disappears. However, anyone here would be with me in that using no config file would be a little unpleasant.

Then my questions are:
What is the easiest way to solve this problem?
What is causing it? Is really something related with regular expressions (I have tried placing a '\' before the '?' without results)'?

Comment: "However, anyone here would be with me in that using no config file would be a little unpleasant." I'm not with you on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [matchit plugin](https://github.com/tmhedberg/matchit) (which most likely is already installed in your computer as the function causing the error, `Match_wrapper()`, is defined on matchit.vim. To check if matchit.vim is loaded, use the command `:scriptnames` in Vim). Then add this auto command to .vimrc:

```
autocmd! BufWinEnter,BufEnter *   if exists("b:match_words") | 
                                \   let b:match_words=b:match_words.',¿:?' |
                                \ endif
```

To keep .vimrc clean you may want to follow the advice on `help :matchit`:

> ... you can add autocommands to the script or to your vimrc file, but the recommended method is to add a line such as
>
> ```
> let b:match_words = '\<foo\>:\<bar\>'
> ```
>
> to the filetype-plugin for your language.

Comment: Thank you, It worked perfectly. Just an extra question: What is the meaning of the comma in ',¿:?'?. It seems to well without it.

Comment: The variable `b:match_words`  usually contains other patterns, the comma ensures `¿:?` is properly appended. Do `echo b:match_words` to see the list of patterns